# Sorting only odd elements of an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

If I have an **associative array** like

- 3 => 50
- 4 => 12
- 5 => 45
- 6 => 89
- 7 => 5
- 8 => 1

Now I want to sort only the values of **odd keys in ascending order**.
The output should be:

- 7 => 5
- 4 => 12
- 5 => 45
- 6 => 89
- 3 => 50
- 8 => 1

Comment: Well I can't see you attempting doing anything, show us the code and we can try to help you.

Comment: Your question hardly makes any sense. If we are trying to get the odd keys, then how come we are expecting 4 => 12 6 => 89 and 8 => 1 ?  4, 6 and 8 are even.

Comment: You said, "sort only the values of odd keys in ascending order" but your expected output that you show to us is not like that.

Comment: If you solve this answer your question because I'm curious on how you'd do this.

Answer (score 2):

To maintain original keys, you have to first separate even and odd elements:

```
$odd = $even = array();
array_walk( $array, function( $val, $key ) use ( &$odd, &$even ) { ( $key % 2 ) ? $odd[$key] = $val : $even[$key] = $val; });
```

Then, sort `$odd` array:

```
asort( $odd );
```

At the end, you reconstruct the array:

```
$array = array();
while( current( $odd ) || current( $even ) )
{
    if( current( $odd ) )  $array[key($odd)]  = current( $odd );
    if( current( $even ) ) $array[key($even)] = current( $even );
    next( $odd );
    next( $even );
}
print_r( $array );
```

<kbd>**[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/552369)**</kbd>

Note that your question is a bit ambiguous: it's not totally clear if you base odd/even on key value or key position: this solution consider key values and — trough `while` and `if` checks — guarantee that all values are preserved, even if you have more even than odd keys (or *vice-versa*).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    3 => 50,
    4 => 12,
    5 => 45,
    6 => 89,
    7 => 5,
    8 => 1
);

$oddElems = array();
$evenElems = array();

$i = 0;
foreach($array as $index => $value)
{
    if($i % 2 == 0)
        $oddElems[$index] = $value;
    else
        $evenElems[$index] = $value;

    $i++;
}

//sort odd elements
asort($oddElems);

$result = array();
while(!empty($oddElems) || !empty($evenElems))
{
    $lastEvenElemKey = array_keys($evenElems, end($evenElems))[0];
    $evenElem = array_pop($evenElems);
    if($evenElem !== null)
        $result[$lastEvenElemKey] = $evenElem;

    $lastOddElemKey = array_keys($oddElems, end($oddElems))[0];
    $oddElem = array_pop($oddElems);
    if($oddElem !== null)
        $result[$lastOddElemKey] = $oddElem;

}
echo '<pre>';

$result = array_reverse($result, true);
print_r($result);
```

Result is:

```
Array
(
    [7] => 5
    [4] => 12
    [5] => 45
    [6] => 89
    [3] => 50
    [8] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do this in PHP, is this what you are looking for ?

```
$array(3 => 50, 4 => 12, 5 => 45, 6 => 89, 7 => 5, 8 => 1);
function sort_it($array) {
    $final_array[];
    $array_only_odd_keys[];
    $array_only_odd_stuff[];
    $array_only_even_keys[];
    $array_only_even_stuff[];
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {

        if($key & 1) {
            //Key is odd
            array_push($array_only_odd_stuff,  $key => $value);
            array_push($array_only_odd_keys,  $key);
        }
        else {
            // Key is even
            array_push($array_only_even_stuff,  $key => $value);
            array_push($array_only_even_keys,  $key);
        }
    }
    $array_only_odd_keys = asort($array_only_odd_keys);
    for ($x = 0; $x <= count($array)/2; $x++) {
        if ($x & 1) {
            array_push($final_array, $array_only_odd_keys[$x],     $array_only_odd_stuff[$array_only_odd_keys[$x]]);
        }
        else {
            array_push($final_array, $array_only_even_keys[$x],     $array_only_odd_stuff[$array_only_even_keys[$x]]);
        }
    } 
    return $final_array;
```

This is how i'd do it in PHP though only if you want the final array to switch between even and odd keys like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to separate the array into even and odd arrays, sort the odd array, and then glue them back together:

```
$odd = $even = [];
foreach (array_chunk($myArray, 2, true) as $pair) {
    $odd += array_slice($pair, 0, 1, true);
    $even += array_slice($pair, 1, 1, true);
}

asort($odd);

$result = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($odd); $i++) {
    $result += array_slice($odd, $i, 1, true);
    $result += array_slice($even, $i, 1, true);
}
```

This rather naïve implementation assumes there is an equal number of odd and even numbers, they're always alternating and the array starts with an odd number.